# Help how do i disable the status bar

Tags: settings, screen, notification-bar

I usually hand over my Samsung Note 3 to my kids to watch Netflix , videos and play games etc. I recently notice that my status bar will not take off, I looked at every settings option, and I can't find the option to turn it off. I would appreciate if someone can help me thank you.

Comment: Jose, it might help if you explicitly mention which Android version you're on. With 5.0+ you could e.g. "lock your kids in" by pinning the foreground app (so they can't get out of it). Not sure whether that also hides the status bar (cannot test, have no Lollipop yet).

Comment: Best way that use gravitybox to change status bar and icon on statusbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Android Lollipop then as Izzy suggested, you can [turn on the Screen Pinning](http://gadgetguideonline.com/android/lollipop/how-to-use-screen-pinning-in-android-lollipop/) to stay in a particular app and hide the status bar.

If not on Lollipop then third party launchers such as Apex and Nova allow you to do this only in the home screen and app drawer screen.

As in the feature section you can see that you can hide the status bar,

> Hide elements as you want (persistent search bar, status bar, or even
>   the dock)

But this only hides the status bar in Home screen and the status bar becomes active once you open a specific app. Instead the developer of the app should have implemented the immersive model to hide the status and action bar.

But as mentioned in your question most games will hide the status bar and videos played with fullscreen does hides the status bar.

**UPDATE:**

Use [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc) and in the toggle actions use the **Immersive mode** and start any app you want. The app will start with the status bar and the action bar(Back, Home and Recent buttons) hidden and you can switch back to normal mode by clicking the toggling Immersive mode or to quicky display the status bar swipe from the top of the screen twice to display any notifications.

Comment: PS: [All in One Gestures](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures) also allows toggling immersive mode (and to define several other useful gestures) :)

Comment: Oh wow thank you , but it did not work , I recently checked my device version and it says " 5.0 " not sure if I mention , I have a galaxy note 3. Sorry about the little information I'm giving and thanks 4 helping an old man.

Comment: @JoseSanchez you are using Lollipop version..you can use the Screen Pinning option and it comes default in phone..so you don't need to install any app..you need to turn on the screen pinning feautre first to use it. turn it on in the settings-> security menu and in recent tabs you can see that you can pin the apps you want..then the back and home button wont work..to unpin an app you need to touch the back and recent keys simulatneously..i don't know why this will not work..have you tried the screen pinning or the power toggles app..both are working in my case and i'm also using the version 5.